# Accessing histogram in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology, histogram

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10, I need the histogram of the frequency to heights distribution like in the attached picture.

Is there another toolkit to access this data?

A screenshot is not suitable. The attribute table is not helpful, too.

[image: Symbology]

Comment: Rizwan Here how to remove the clouds in images using Histogram , i want to set the neasrest values with replacement of clouds ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two ways which usually works quite well for me are

1. Histogram graphs which you can create from View menu > Graphs. Tutorial on [that](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00330000000p000000).
2. Statistics window which can be opened from the attribute table. Right-click the column name and choose Statistics.

If you want to create a more professional histogram, you could use external libraries such as Python libraries or [R](http://www.r-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first way is rather helpful, but i cannot access the real count values like in my image. But Thank you anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "real count values". When you create a histogram graph the count is on Y axis and value on X axis.

Comment: Am I missing something or can't the **Make Graph** and/or **Save Graph** Tools do what's needed?

Comment: Or the Graph Wizard under the View Menu-->Graphs-->Create Graph...

Comment: With real values, i meant in like in the screenshot. On X are heights and on Y are their abundance/frequency. In another forum someone said without scrips or mathlab, this screenshot seems the only "easy" way.

Answer (score 0):

The histogram can also be easily created by the **Geostatistical Analyst** (Geostatistical-Analyst-License needed).

- Open Geostatistical Analyst toolbar
- Choose "Explore Data" --> "Histogram" (or another type of statistical plot)

Further information and examples:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/histograms.htm